# Using jquery fileopen dialog in webpart

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

I am using  webpart to upload some files to list in sharepoint. I have got code to upload data to list. What i need is Jquery control to select file and then i will use that file to upload to my list. Here is my code to update list but i just need some jquery control to select file. I dont want to use fileupload control as it comes with its own textbox and browse button.

```
SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl).OpenWeb();
site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

Stream fStream = File1.PostedFile.InputStream;// i need file here through jquery 
byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];

fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
fStream.Close();

site.Files.Add(destUrl, contents);
```